# Breeze.js with Katana middleware

Tags: breeze

I have not had the opportunity to test more I wonder if it is possible to be all right migrate to the full asp.net WebApi to Katana middleware.
There are some sample project or references? 
I did not notice something in breeze.js.samples repository.

Comment: Take a look at the breeze.server.net repo.

Comment: Checked the repository but have not verified something "Owin" based, only HttpApplication. But I believe that everything will go well.